# Stacked bars with hue in seaborn and pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, stacked-chart

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["type", "App","Feature1", "Feature2","Feature3",
                           "Feature4","Feature5",
                           "Feature6","Feature7","Feature8"], 
                  data=[["type1", "SHA",0,0,1,5,1,0,1,0],
                        ["type2", "LHA",1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0],
                        ["type2", "FRA",1,0,2,1,1,0,1,1],
                        ["type1", "BRU",0,0,1,0,3,0,0,0],
                        ["type2", "PAR",0,1,1,4,1,0,1,0],
                        ["type2", "AER",0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0],
                        ["type1", "SHE",0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0]])
```

I want to make a stacked bar with `type` as a hue. This is, in the x axis I want the features, and for each feature I want 2 stacked bars, one for `type1` and one for `type2`.

For instance, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47138563/4107770) they explain how to make a stacked bar plot with seaborn when the column `type` is dropped. Instead, I want for each feature two stacked bars. **Note**: the values of `App` are shared for `type1` and `type2`

For instance, if I just plot the stacked bars corresponding to type1, I get this:

[image]

I want to make a stacked bar plot where for each feature there are two stacked bars, one for type1, and the other one for type2

Comment: The `App` for each type is different in your sample. What is your expected output?

Comment: @QuangHoang In this case, it is... however, it might be the case that app is shared between types. The expected output is a total of 8x2=16 stacked bars, grouped by feature (each group contains two bars, one for type1 and for type2). The stacked bars show the amount of "apps" for each feature, e.g. for feature 3, the type2 stacked bar would be a bar of height 1 for LHA, a bar of height 2 for FRA, a bar of height 1 for PAR, and a bar of height 1 for AER. Conversely, for feature 3, the type1 stacked bar would be a bar of height 1 for SHA and a bar of height 1 for BRU

Comment: @QuangHoang and the colours of each app bar would be different

Comment: @QuangHoang I edited the question to post an image

Answer (score 0):

I don't think seaborn has a function for barplots that are both stacked and grouped. But you can do it in matplotlib itself by hand. Here is an [example](https://gist.github.com/ctokheim/6435202a1a880cfecd71).

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is the [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) Function

```
d = df.drop(columns='App')
d = d.melt('type', var_name='a', value_name='b')

sns.barplot(x='a', y='b', data=d, hue='type')
```